# Finding strings in the text section

Tags: c, gcc

I have as example the following code:

```
Foo( "Test1" );

void Foo(const char* const i_Test )
{
     // Some logic
}
```

The `i_Test` pointer in `Foo()` hold a pointer to the string in the `.rodata section`.

Is there any way to search the `i_Text` pointer value in the binary file to find the related String? Or can I produce any debug info using the `gcc` that will hold that info?

Comment: I've never seen a double `const` before

Comment: double const on a pointer: first const forbids changing the value that i_Test points to (as example *i_Test='a'), second pointer forbids changing the pointer itself (as example ++i_Test)

Comment: @Yoav "second pointer forbids..." prolly meant "second *const* forbids..."

Comment: Have you used the strings command on your binary.

Comment: Did not understand your question - In the binary I can obviously see these strings, but how can I reach it by Offset? Is there no tool/Debug option in the GCC that can dump the string pointers in the text?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Are you looking for a way to go from a location in memory (i_Text) to an offset in a file? If so, look at the output of "readelf --sections" when run on your program.... however, note that unless you are using a rather unusual configuration, the string "Test1" will not be stored in .text, it will probably be in .rodata.

Comment: You can scan your own binary.

Comment: Correct - I was mistaken it is in the .rodata (question updated). Does in the readelf I can find the string by offset. Relating your question - I want to do a free-text logger that will not format the string, will store the pointer to the format and to formatting (sprintf) in offline tool

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are talking about the **ELF** file format, constant strings are stored in the **.rodata** *(read-only-data)* section. Basically, only instructions (code) of your program are stored in the **.text** section in that binary file. You can investigate these sections by using an object dump program (e.g. [objdump](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html)) like the following:

```
objdump -drS program.o           // to see .text section of your program

objdump -s -j .rodata program.o  // to see .rodata section of your program
```

In your example code above, the `"Test1"` string that you are passing to your `Foo` function will be treated as a constant string by the *compiler*. Thus, you can find its relative memory address before the *loading stage* and the `i_Test` pointer will be pointing to this constant string. However, if you have compiled your code as [position independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (by using the `-fPIC` option in **gcc**), you may also find that the compiler will add a *writable* attribute to that read-only **.rodata** section. Furthermore, you may also use the [readelf](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/readelf.html) binary utility to display detailed information about the sections of your ELF formatted object file.

More information about the **ELF** file format can be found [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what needed. Now, since I am using dynamic linking on my platform I have to find out how to get the libraries .rodata

Answer (score 12):

Actually, constant strings are not kept in the .text section, but in the .rodata section.

In order to see all your constant strings, you can run:

`readelf -S ./[your binary file]`

Note the section number for the .rodata section from the output above

`readelf -p [.rodata section number you got before] ./[your binary name]`

What this command does is print all strings inside a section, since the strings are constant data, you'll get all the strings in the file. You can also alter these strings by calculating the .rodata section address and the offset within it, but I find it much easier to open a hex editor, look for the string and manipulate it (assuming I'm not changing to a longer string)

EDIT

You can use `readelf -p .rodata` directly instead of providing the section number

Comment: This also prints some kind of starting address of the strings !